# Target Selector not working on Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm having a problem with "Pull to refresh". I'm using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside, the `UIRefreshControl` target is set as here below:

```
    public func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
        updateData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [...]

        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("refresh:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }
```

When I pull - there is an exception:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Income.MainVC refresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf1040a9e0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3, the first parameter is no longer ignored by default. In Swift 2, your refresh method signature was `refresh(_:)`, now it's `refresh(sender:)`, so `Selector("refresh:")` won't work.

I suggest you add an underscore to your first parameter so it looks like this `func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject)`.

I would also suggest that you use the new Selector syntax, which should look something like this `#selector(refresh(_:))`

If you use the new Selector syntax (you should) I think you can also keep the first argument and have it look like this `#selector(refresh(sender:))`

Answer (score 5):

Read couple of tutorials.

In iOS10 `UIRefreshControl` added to TableViews.

Simple code I used in my homeproject:

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshData(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

        fetchFixtures()

    }

    func refreshData(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        fetchFixtures()

        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Comment: @odvan just spent two hours on this till I came across your example.  Thanks@